# Every deployment of angular needs hard refresh ( cmd/ctrl + shift + r )

Tags: angular, version

Whenever I do new deployment of angular project. Changes of new deployment are not reflected on browser. To get new changes I need to do cache clear and hard reload ( cmd/ctrl + shift + r ). I am maintaining version number in `package.json` and also  `"outputHashing": "all"`

Comment: angular build can have multiple configuration , please check if hashes are really changing after each build , first build and remember the hash of main.<hash>.js file and then delete build and build it again and check, if hashes are different then its browser issue , if hashes are same , please provide angular.json contents